# Using `\renewcommand\footnoterule{}`in mdframed

Tags: footnotes, mdframed

I am trying to remove a separator line for footnotes in mdframed environment. I tried using `\renewcommand\footnoterule{}` inside the mdframed environment, but this doesn't seem to work.

When I had to change the footnote symbol I had to use some temp values like this:

```
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\color{white}{$\dagger$}}
```

Are there any similar temp values for `\footnoterule` as well? It would be fine if I could either remove the black line or make it white...

---

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{vprasanje}{%
    font=\normalsize,
    linecolor=red,
    outerlinewidth=0pt,
    roundcorner=2pt,
    innertopmargin=4pt,
    innerbottommargin=4pt,
    innerrightmargin=10pt,
    innerleftmargin=10pt,
    backgroundcolor=red,
    settings={\definecolor{linkcolor}{RGB}{255,255,255}}}

\usepackage{footmisc}
\def\footnotelayout{\color{white}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[style=vprasanje]
\renewcommand\footnoterule{}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\color{white}{$\dagger$}}
\textcolor{white}{This is a footnote\footnote{You can see that line is still there and color is black...}}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

**rendered**:

[image]

Comment: Please **do** provide a **MWE**, that help others to help you. But you should know that by now...

Comment: I thought my question was straight forward...

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it is. but for someone to **test** and provide their solution(s) they'd need to type the whole code, that does not sound very appealing, IMHO.

Comment: Ok. Here it is. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick glance at `mdframed.sty` shows (l. 745ff) that the package uses the internal macro `\mdf@footnoterule` instead of the "standard" `\footnoterule` (which is rather sensible). This internal macro is defined by

```
\newrobustcmd*\mdf@footnoterule{%
    \kern0\p@%
    \hrule \@width 1in \kern 2.6\p@}
```

(Don't ask me why `\kern0\p@` instead of simply `\kern\z@`.) If you want to remove the line once and for all, one quick&dirty trick is simply to place

```
\makeatletter
\def\mdf@footnoterule{}
\makeatother
```

somewhere in the preamble. I think it should be safe, as this is used only by the macro actually typesetting the footnote.

**EDIT:** If you want to do something else, like change the color, you can adapt the code to your needs, like

```
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*\mdf@footnoterule{%
    {\color{white}\kern0\p@%
    \hrule \@width 1in \kern 2.6\p@}}
\makeatother
```

Please notice 1) the use of `\renewrobustcmd*` and 2) the additional grouping around `\color{white}`. The latter is not strictly necessary in your MWE, as you are writing the text in white anyway, but it would matter otherwise.

Comment: Do you maybe have an idea on how to make same line white?

Comment: @71GA See edit.